# Chiku Span with variable offset

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write a Chiku Span indicator that will automatically adjust the offset as per the chart using the following offsets

5 Min = -825 ; 15 Min = -275 ; 30 Min = -137 and 1 Hr = -69

```
//@version=5
indicator("MTF Chiku Span",overlay = true)

Sma = ta.sma(close,1)
Offset=(-69)//,title = "Offset")


res = input.string(title='Set Multi Time Frames', options = ["5", "15","30","60"], defval="60",group = "Offset Options")
ma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, close)
var OS = switch res
    "5 Min"  => -825
    "15 Min" => -275
    "30 Min" => -137
    "1 Hr"   => -69
plot(ma,offset= Offset,color = color.yellow,linewidth = 2)
//plot(Sma,offset = OS, title='Show Last Highs',color = color.yellow, trackprice=true, linewidth = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your switch statement so that what you are switching matches the selection. Otherwise it will never switch your offset.

```
res = input.string(title='Set Multi Time Frames', options = ["5", "15","30","60"], defval="60",group = "Offset Options")
ma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, close)
var OS = switch res
    "5"  => -825
    "15" => -275
    "30" => -137
    "60" => -69
```

Comment: Hallo Smashapalooza, I am lost I change "string" to "timeframe" . What happens now is that whatever the dafval value is eg 60 the offset = -69. If I change the defval value to eg   5 the offset = -825. I have no idee how to fix it

Comment: Do you want offsets that large?

Comment: Yes because it points out highs/ lows - 3 days ago. I manage to fix the script using the "if / else" functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your advise pointed me in a different direction and as I say I manage to rewrite the script to get the desired result.